# unix Diff utility - how to generates output file without < or >?

Tags: bash, unix, text-files, diff

I am using diff to see the differenceS between 2 files.
It generates the output like:

```
some numbers here
< gi|description1
< ADGCAAAGGCC
---
> gi|description3
> GGCCTAAGGGG
```

Can I produce the output like:

```
gi|description1
ADGCAAAGGCC
gi|description3
GGCCTAAGGGG
```

without `<` , `>` ,`---` , `the first numbers line` ????

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly you can modify the output of the `diff` utility to your liking. In the end it is a utility in the typical unix tradition, so one would expect it to be tweakable into all directions :-)

The "man page" explains the options and points out the `...-line-format` options for this. Take a look yourself: `man diff`...

This leads to a command like this:

```
diff --unchanged-line-format="" --old-line-format="%L" --new-line-format="%L" file1 file2
```

It outputs only lines that have changed and for those simply the literal old and new form without any further indication marks. Which is what you want, according to your example.